# How I can group results in the sql query by groups with interval?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

I have the following data in a mysql table

```
|id|value|date|
|1|88|2015-08-26 08:00:00|
|2|88|2015-08-26 09:00:00|
|3|76|2015-08-26 10:00:00|
|4|76|2015-08-26 11:00:00|
|5|88|2015-08-26 12:00:00|
|6|76|2015-08-26 13:00:00|
|7|76|2015-08-26 14:00:00|
|8|76|2015-08-26 15:00:00|
|9|94|2015-08-26 16:00:00|
|10|94|2015-08-26 17:00:00|
|11|63|2015-08-26 18:00:00|
|12|94|2015-08-26 19:00:00|
```

I want to generate the following result:

```
|value|min date|max date|
|88|2015-08-26 08:00:00|2015-08-26 09:00:00|
|76|2015-08-26 10:00:00|2015-08-26 11:00:00|
|88|2015-08-26 12:00:00|2015-08-26 12:00:00|
|76|2015-08-26 13:00:00|2015-08-26 15:00:00|
|94|2015-08-26 16:00:00|2015-08-26 17:00:00|
|63|2015-08-26 18:00:00|2015-08-26 18:00:00|
|94|2015-08-26 19:00:00|2015-08-26 19:00:00|
```

I want to group the results that had the same value by 'date intervals'.

What is the query I need to write to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean with "grouping by date intervals"?

Comment: Here is the definition. If the same id abuts itself (**in PK order**), it is grouped. Enter: Variables

Comment: @jarlh The only state I think his table has to do the query is the combination of the `id` and `date`.

Comment: Yeah, I later realized OP asks for a schedule, from 8:00 to 19:00.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please have a look at this question, thanks.

Comment: @jarlh, under "grouping by date intervals" I mean that results shouldn't be grouped by simple "group by", becouse in this case I receive only 4 rows. But I want to receive sequence..  every value in own schedule, in turn. Oh God, sorry for my "good" English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Schema:

```
create table thing1
(   id int not null,
    value int not null,
    dt datetime not null
);
insert thing1 (id,value,dt) values
(1,88,'2015-08-26 08:00:00'),
(2,88,'2015-08-26 09:00:00'),
(3,76,'2015-08-26 10:00:00'),
(4,76,'2015-08-26 11:00:00'),
(5,88,'2015-08-26 12:00:00'),
(6,76,'2015-08-26 13:00:00'),
(7,76,'2015-08-26 14:00:00'),
(8,76,'2015-08-26 15:00:00'),
(9,94,'2015-08-26 16:00:00'),
(10,94,'2015-08-26 17:00:00'),
(11,63,'2015-08-26 18:00:00'),
(12,94,'2015-08-26 19:00:00');
```

### Query:

```
set @grp := 0, @value:=0;
select value,min(dt) as min_date,max(dt) as max_date
from 
( 
  select id,value,dt,
      @grp := if(@value <> value, @grp + 1, @grp) as grouping,
      @value := value as drewisdummy
  from thing1
  order by id
) xxx
group by grouping
```

### Results:

```
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| value | min_date            | max_date            |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    88 | 2015-08-26 08:00:00 | 2015-08-26 09:00:00 |
|    76 | 2015-08-26 10:00:00 | 2015-08-26 11:00:00 |
|    88 | 2015-08-26 12:00:00 | 2015-08-26 12:00:00 |
|    76 | 2015-08-26 13:00:00 | 2015-08-26 15:00:00 |
|    94 | 2015-08-26 16:00:00 | 2015-08-26 17:00:00 |
|    63 | 2015-08-26 18:00:00 | 2015-08-26 18:00:00 |
|    94 | 2015-08-26 19:00:00 | 2015-08-26 19:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT value, min(date) AS 'min date', max(date) AS 'max date'
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY round((hour(date)/8)+1,0),value
```

It seems like your results are grouped by quarters of the day.

Comment: I am a big fan of group by 1, and order by 1,2 .... til my peers see it. Then all hell breaks out

Comment: I love doing that though